# Change in the optional parameter is not reloading the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Below is the route :

```
<Route exact  path="/products/version/:id/:version" component={component} />
```

I am trying to redirect from : http://localhost:8080/products/version/600178221/3
to 
http://localhost:8080/products/version/600178221/5

using  : 
  this.props.history.push('/products/version/600178221/5');

Issue : URL is updating, but component is not re-loading.

Comment: Try wrap router.jsx with `withRouter` 
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
...
...
withRouter(Routes);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React won't re-render your component because only the props changed but the component that has to be rendered is still the same. React only updates what is necessary to update.

If you get your product data from a remote backend (using ajax) I recommend you use `componentDidUpdate`. This is also recommended in the official documentation as an alternative for `getDerivedStateFromProps` for side effects:

> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.
>
> *[React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)*

```
componendDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { match } = this.props;

    if (prevProps.match.params.id !== match.params.id || prevProps.match.params.version !== match.params.version) {
        this.fetchDataFromApi();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with componentDidMount, You also need to implement the componentWillReceiveProps or use getDerivedStateFromProps(from v16.3.0 onwards) in Products page since the same component is re-rendered with updated params and not re-mounted when you change the route params, this is because params are passed as props to the component and on props change, React components re-render and not re-mounted.

EDIT: from v16.3.0 use getDerivedStateFromProps to set/update state based on props(no need to specify it in two different lifecyle methods)

````
    ```static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
     if (nextProps.match.params.product !== prevState.currentProductId){
  const currentProductId = nextProps.match.params.product
  const result = productlist.products.filter(obj => {

    return obj.id === currentProductId;

  })
 return {

    product: result[0],
    currentId: currentProductId,
    result

  }
  }
 return null;
 }```
````